# Sieve of Eratosthenes implementations and comparisons

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Besides the simple implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes with time complexity of O(N log log N), I also tried to implement a modification with time complexity O(N). Although, both produce the desired result, somehow the earlier one takes much lesser time compared to the next one and I'm unable to figure out why. I'd really appreciate some pointers on this.

Implementation 1:

```
def build_sieve_eratosthenes(num):
    ## Creates sieve of size (num+1) to correct for 0-indexing.
    primes_sieve = [1] * (num+1)
    primes_sieve[0] = primes_sieve[1] = 0
    for p in range(2, num):
        if primes_sieve[p] == 1:
            for mul in range(2*p, num+1, p):
                primes_sieve[mul] = 0
    return primes_sieve
```

Implementation 2:

```
def build_sieve_eratosthenes_linear(num):
    ## Creates sieve of size (num+1) to correct for 0-indexing.
    primes_sieve = [1] * (num+1)
    primes_sieve[0] = primes_sieve[1] = 0

    ## Builds a list of size (num+1) recording the smallest prime factor of each number.
    SPF = [1] * (num+1)

    ## Builds a list of all primes seen so far with pos indicator of position where to insert the next prime.
    ## Uses a large fixed memory allocation scheme to avoid the usage of append list operation.
    primes = [0] * num
    pos = 0

    for p in range(2, num+1):
        if primes_sieve[p] == 1:
            primes[pos] = p
            pos = pos + 1
            ## Smallest prime factor of a prime is a prime itself.
            SPF[p] = p
        for i in range(0, pos):
            if p * primes[i] <= num and primes[i] <= SPF[p]:
                primes_sieve[p*primes[i]] = 0
                SPF[p * primes[i]] = primes[i]
            else:
                break
    return primes_sieve

test_num = 2000000
```

Test method

```
def find_sum_of_primes_upto_num_with_sieve(sieve, num):
    primes_sieve = sieve(num)
    primes_sum = 0
    for n in range(len(primes_sieve)):
        if primes_sieve[n] == 1:
            primes_sum = primes_sum + n
    return primes_sum
```

Results:

```
start2 = time.time()
sum_2 = find_sum_of_primes_upto_num_with_sieve(build_sieve_eratosthenes, test_num)
end2 = time.time()
print("Sum of primes obtained: ", sum_2)
print("Time taken by checking primality of each number is %f sec" % (end2 - start2))
```

Sum of primes obtained:  142913828922
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.647822 sec

```
start3 = time.time()
sum_3 = find_sum_of_primes_upto_num_with_sieve(build_sieve_eratosthenes_linear, test_num)
end3 = time.time()
print("Sum of primes obtained: ", sum_3)
print("Time taken by checking primality of each number is %f sec" % (end3 - start3))
```

Sum of primes obtained:  142913828922
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 1.561308 sec

Comment: You can consider to write your idea in algorithm format, I don't know python but I have some interest in prime number related works.

Comment: You implementation doesn't seem like O(n), you have an inner loop there.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-eratosthenes-0n-time-complexity/ to understand why it is O(N)

Comment: I saw that, the writer claimed it O(n) but it's not definitely. And it requires much more memory (at least 4 times than Sieve of Eratosthenes) which causes more delay.

Comment: What does it mean by "Sum of primes obtained: 142913828922"? total number of primes? what is the highest prime you found in this code?

Comment: It claims O(n) in time not in memory. Also the sum of primes is up to 2 million in this case.

Comment: Thta's why your second implementation runs slower (managing much memory). My code (in java) finds all the primes upto 20 millions in 0.114 sec. Well, time depends on machine as well.

Comment: And how much time does the first implementation take for you (in Java)?

Comment: I'm talking about first implementation (Sieve of Eratosthenes), For 200 millions it takes 2.482 secods. Second one will definitely take more time, I don't want to write code for that unless I really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dropped a simple iteration counter into each routine, and ran for powers of 10 from 10^3 through 10^7

build_sieve_eratosthenes:

```
    1000 has     1958 iterations in sieve
   10000 has    23071 iterations in sieve
  100000 has   256808 iterations in sieve
 1000000 has  2775210 iterations in sieve
10000000 has 29465738 iterations in sieve
```

build_sieve_eratosthenes_linear:

```
    1000 has      831 iterations in sieve_linear
   10000 has     8770 iterations in sieve_linear
  100000 has    90407 iterations in sieve_linear
 1000000 has   921501 iterations in sieve_linear
10000000 has  9335420 iterations in sieve_linear
```

Your `linear` function is *not* linear: note that inner loop, which runs `pos` times ... and `pos` is a count of the quantity of primes found, which is *not* a constant.

`linear` grows more slowly than the "normal" function, and has significantly fewer iterations overall.  However, it has a larger cost for each iteration, which is why you're seeing "inverted" times.  Each number found and each "cross-out" is more expensive in your `linear` function; the slower growth hasn't caught up by your limit of only 2*10^6, not by my limit of 10*7.  You could extrapolate this out for about a day to get a better feel of the appropriate timing, if that's worth it to you ... but the central "problem" is the slower processing for each number.

For the detail-curious, here's the full output:

```
1000 has 1958 iterations in sieve
Sum of primes obtained:  76127
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.000904 sec
10000 has 23071 iterations in sieve
Sum of primes obtained:  5736396
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.008270 sec
100000 has 256808 iterations in sieve
Sum of primes obtained:  454396537
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.067962 sec
1000000 has 2775210 iterations in sieve
Sum of primes obtained:  37550402023
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.428727 sec
10000000 has 29465738 iterations in sieve
Sum of primes obtained:  3203324994356
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 5.761439 sec
1000 has 831 iterations in sieve_linear
Sum of primes obtained:  76127
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.001069 sec
10000 has 8770 iterations in sieve_linear
Sum of primes obtained:  5736396
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.010398 sec
100000 has 90407 iterations in sieve_linear
Sum of primes obtained:  454396537
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 0.107276 sec
1000000 has 921501 iterations in sieve_linear
Sum of primes obtained:  37550402023
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 1.087080 sec
10000000 has 9335420 iterations in sieve_linear
Sum of primes obtained:  3203324994356
Time taken by checking primality of each number is 11.008726 sec
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this simple yet insightful idea of adding a counter and noting the expense per iteration.

Comment: Also, I like your suggestion regarding taking up the limit. But a limitation here is that I also build arrays with memory allocation of that limit. And it may not be possible to allocate memory with an increasing limit.

Comment: First, note that you need find only primes up to `N` in order to identify primes up to `N^2`.  Second, if you need to identify large primes -- beyond your capacity to allocate the Sieve -- then you need to research methods for doing so.  The Sieve is not really an effective way to find primes past a certain point.  That point depends on your hardware and how long you care to wait.  I switch over between about 10^8 and 10^15, depending on the application.  I also maintain files of primes I've generated, so I can just read those in for general use, or to bootstrap a new application.